# Subquery - case when - subselect - group by - count

Tags: sql, db2

Given 2 tables, I need a grouped summary of the awards for a shopping. More items means more awards.

tab_basket

| id | name | shopping_no | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | Mike | 00001 | A |
| 002 | Mike | 00001 | A |
| 003 | Mike | 00001 | A |
| 004 | Tom | 00002 | B |
| 005 | Tom | 00002 | B |
| 006 | Tony | 00003 | A |
| 007 | Heinz | 00004 | A |

tab_award

| items | award | type_award |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0.05 | A |
| 2 | 0.50 | A |
| 3 | 0.90 | A |
| 4 | 1.00 | A |
| 1 | 0.15 | B |
| 2 | 0.70 | B |
| 3 | 1.10 | B |
| 4 | 1.30 | B |

I need following table as result.

| award | items | shopping_no | type _award |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0.90 | 3 | 00001 | A |
| 0.70 | 2 | 00002 | B |
| 0.05 | 1 | 00003 | A |
| 0.05 | 1 | 00004 | A |

My solution attempt. I every time only get null as result for award (the else result) or the error "sql0811 result of select more than one row".
I am happy for any help, thanks!

```
SELECT          award,
                items,
                shopping_no,
                type_award
FROM            tab_basket t
LEFT OUTER JOIN tab_award u ON t.TYPE = u.type_award
                           AND CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(shopping_no)
                                            FROM tab_basket m
                                           WHERE t.id = m.id
                                             AND t.name = m.name
                                             AND t.shopping_no = m.shopping_no
                                             AND t.TYPE = u.TYPE
                                           GROUP BY shopping_no ) = '1' THEN '1'
                               case WHEN (SELECT COUNT(shopping_no)
                                            FROM tab_basket m
                                           WHERE t.id = m.id
                                             AND t.name = m.name
                                             AND t.shopping_no = m.shopping_no
                                             AND t.TYPE = u.TYPE
                                           GROUP BY shopping_no ) = '2' THEN '2' 
                               CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(shopping_no)
                                            FROM tab_basket m
                                           WHERE t.id = m.id
                                             AND t.name = m.name
                                             AND t.shopping_no = m.shopping_no
                                             AND t.TYPE = u.TYPE                                                                                                                  
                                           GROUP BY shopping_no ) = '3' THEN '3'
                               CASE WHEN (SELECT COUNT(shopping_no)
                                            FROM tab_basket m
                                           WHERE t.id = m.id
                                             AND t.name = m.name                                                                                                                   
                                             AND t.shopping_no = m.shopping_no                                                                                                                                 
                                             AND t.TYPE = u.TYPE                                                                                                                    
                                           GROUP BY shopping_no ) = '4' THEN '4'
                               ELSE 'no_price'                                                                                                   
                                END = u.award
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first aggregate your tab_basket table and then can join that with tab_award table -

```
SELECT TB.award, TB.items, TA.shopping_no, TB.type_award
  FROM (SELECT name, shopping_no, type, COUNT(*) CNT
          FROM tab_basket
         GROUP BY name, shopping_no, type) TB
  JOIN tab_award TA ON TB.type = TA.type_award
                    AND TB.CNT = TA.items
```